How to prevent Word on Mac OS X from deleting/renaming an already saved document?
I am using MS Word (Ver 16.77) on Mac OS X (Monterey, 12.1.1), with Mendeley Desktop plug-in to insert references.
I was making edits to an already saved file when Word crashed and deleted the file, or perhaps moved it somewhere else (which I have not been able to find).
How can this be prevented in the future? It happened twice already. And how can I find out where Word put the file?
Some forums suggest that MS Word renames files to indecipherable names and sticks them in places like ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/, but I couldn't find my file there. I cannot find any explanation for this catastrophic bug.
I want to avoid updating MS Word because the recent version I tried crashed every couple of minutes, which led me to downgrade to Ver 16.77.

Can’t you just rollback the commit or revert to an earlier commit? If this was your only copy and you had not yet committed another version of the document it much can be done.

@Ramhound yes but my main question is how to avoid this horrible bug in Word (and secondarily how to find out where Word sticks the file). I edited the question to clarify

What you described was caused by your own actions. Word has always opened a file, create a temporary file, and saved the file when it was closed.

How Office has handled any of it's  document formats is well known, it creates a temporary file that only it can access, then merges any changes into the actual file.  How this works isn't specific to macOS or Windows.  I reference you replacing the file within GIT, I wasn't even suggesting, you were responsible for Word crashing.  Don't put words in my mouth. You only remove the portion about Git 11 minutes ago. I don't know the reason Word is crashing, you provided zero information, to diagnose that problem.  So I will bail, quickly, without any return to this question.
